# LAMP can't access WordPress website

Tags: linux, wordpress, lamp

I've installed LAMP under Ubuntu 14, placed a copy of my WordPress folder files under the /lampstack-5.6.30-0/apache2/htdocs/wordpress/ folder, started LAMP Apache, MySQL...yet each time I try to reach localhost/wordpress/ I get routed automatically to localhost:8888/wordpress/ and get error message

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

I've tried many times to go to localhost:8080/wordpress or localhost/wordpress but I get routed back to localhost:8888/wordpress and see the error message shown above. Can someone please tell me what I might be missing here/ doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww My problem isn't with Linux, LAMP itself as a tool or any 'static site' placed under LAMP htdocs folder, my problem is specifically with WordPress so obviously it might require some changes to Wordpress configuration I am not aware about.  Having said the above when I reviewed the DevOps question and as you can see most agreed upon answer was dasil003 reply whom recommended posting DevOps questions in StackOverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such problem can possibly happen when you move your wp site folder from one folder to the other, so in term of the URL, you need to check your wp DB, specifically the wp_options table [ siteurl, home ] fields, also the wp_posts table, the [ guid ] field.

Making sure the above two tables fields are pointing to localhost:8080/wordpress will solve at least the URL problem.